# How to check if an array has values?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

My data comes from a WordPress database. I would like to have an if statement checking if there's data in the array. If this is the case, I would like to execute some code. If it's not, I would like to execute something else. I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$array_value = array(
    array("")
);

if (empty($array_value)) {
  echo "The array is empty.";
} else {
  echo "The array has a value.";
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a multidimensional array is empty or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401584/how-to-check-if-a-multidimensional-array-is-empty-or-not)

Comment: Check if `$array_value[1]` is empty work 2.

Comment: try the code first ;)

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to check if an array contains values. The first of these will show examples of checking if an array is empty and if an array is not empty. I've also added an example using OP's code.

### Your situation

Here's an example for your situation using the methods proposed below:

```
$array_value = array(
    array("")
);

if (count(current($array_value)) == 0) {
    // There are no values
} else {
    // There are values in $array_value[0]
}
```

If you want more information, feel free to ask.

#### Method 1 - Check if there are values in an array

```
// 1. Check if the array is EMPTY
if (count($array) == 0) {
    // The $array is EMPTY
} else {
    // The $array is NOT EMPTY
}

// 2. Check if the array is NOT EMPTY
if (count($array) > 0) {
    // The $array is NOT EMPTY
} else {
    // The $array is EMPTY
}
```

#### Method 2 - Check for a specific value

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$value = 2;

if (in_array($value, $array)) {
    // $array contains $value
} else {
    // $array doesn not contain $value
}
```

#### Method 3 - Check if the array contains a certain key

```
$array = array(
    'first_key' => array(1, 2, 3),
    'second_key' => array(1, 2, 3)
);

$keyToFind = 'first_key';

if (array_key_exists($keyToFind, $array)) {
    // The key 'first_key' is in $array
} else {
    // The $array does not contain 'first_key'
}
```

#### Resources

- [count() - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)
- [in_array() - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [array_key_exists() - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: Have you test your code with multi-dimensional array?

Comment: use for example the code @user write on question. no one work for check if is empty.

Comment: count($array_value) will print 1 because have an array into array.

Comment: instead of (count($array) == 0) why not ($array !== [])